# Nested foreach - Need to operate on object at each level

Tags: c#

I was trying to refactor some nested `foreach` loops but ran into an issue. This is the original code:

```
foreach(var doc in customTrackerDocuments)
{
    foreach(var rule in doc.Rules)
    {
        foreach(var eval in rule.Evaluations)
        {
            // Do something with customTrackerDocuments, rules, and evaluations
            // doc, rule, and eval are all available here
        }
    }
}
```

It's admittedly clean and straightforward, so maybe it should just stay like that. However, I've always tried to reduce complexity and increase readability, so I tried this:

```
foreach(var eval in customTrackerDocuments.SelectMany(doc => doc.Rules).SelectMany(rule => rule.Evaluations))
{
    // Do something with customTrackerDocuments, rules, and evaluations
    // doc and rule are NOT available here
}
```

The issue is that doc and rule are no longer available to use in the loop. Is there a way to have them be available with this approach? Or should I just use the first option that has the three nested loops?

I have a fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/oBMfQC

Comment: It's not refactoring if it doesn't work afterwards ;-) Also, IMO the original code is readable (I can see instantly what it does)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not available because you're only projecting `rule.Evaluations` in your final `SelectMany`. You could build up an anonymous type:

```
foreach(var eval in customTrackerDocuments.SelectMany(doc => doc.Rules, rule => new {doc, rule})
                                          .SelectMany(docrule => docrule.rule.Evaluations, eval => new {docrule.doc, docrule.rule, eval}))
{
    // eval.doc, eval,rule, eval.eval are available here
}
```

Whether or not that's more readable or less complex is debatable.  It certainly won't be any faster or use less memory.